# How to redirect when accessing root URL Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

According to `php artisan --version`, I am using 5.7.22.

When loggedOut, if user accesses root URL `localhost:8000/`, I would like to redirect him to `localhost:8000/login`.

When loggedIn, if the user accesses again the root URL `localhost:8000/`, I would like to redirect him to `localhost:8000/charts`.

I used the `php artisan make:auth` feature. I am not quite familiar with the defaults in relation to this. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Is it ok to just do a `Route::get('/', 'SampleController@redirectToSomewhere');` in `web.php` or is it better to change default scaffoldings?

In SampleController I did a:

```
public function redirectToSomewhere()
{
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect('/charts');
    } else {
        return redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

but when I try to access `localhost:8000` it gives a `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found`

**EDIT:**

Added `use Auth;` and the function works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is that Use Condition for authentication. If the user is authenticated then redirect him to `localhost:8000/charts` and if authentication fails redirect him to login page.

```
If(Auth::check())
{
```

redirect him to localhost:8000/charts

```
}else{
```

redirect him to localhost:8000/login

```
}
```

Comment: If you are using `Route::get('/', 'SampleController@redirectToSomewhere')` then use the condition in the respective method.

Comment: This is to be done in the SampleController if understand it correctly?

Comment: Yes SampleController is class and inside this class redirectToSomewhere is method which is called as mentioned in your Route

Comment: it says Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found. I updated the post.

Comment: Use `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`

Comment: I did a `use Auth;` I forgot this, my bad. Thanks